# Reschedule AsyncTask to run for next 20 minutes at the interval of 4 minutes if no internet connection is available

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to execute **AsyncTask** on SmsReceiver Broadcast. The problem with my code is that if no internet connection is available when SMS broadcast receiver triggers, the **AsyncTask** does not execute. If no internet connection is available I want to schedule **AsyncTask** to run 5 times at the interval of 4 minutes for the next 20 minutes. If at any execution AsyncTask get response from server then cancel next executions & update UI. I can update UI in onPostExecute(). I earlier asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793363/sometimes-android-broadcastreceiver-does-not-work) but could not get any code help. A lot of posts are available on **ScheduledExecutorService** to schedule AsyncTask to run at interval of x minutes, but I could not find any to post mentioning AsyncTask to run for x minutes at the interval of x minutes. Only on the official Android website a [Beeper example](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is available but I could not understand how to manipulate my code to work. I will be obliged if someone can help me is getting this code work.

**SmsReceiver.java**

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

static boolean flagAlarmSet;
static int count;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED) || action.equals("ActionRetry")) {

        Log.d("SmsReceiver Broadcast triggered", "OK");
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            Log.d("Internet is connected", "flagAlarmSet to: " + flagAlarmSet);

            //if (flagAlarmSet) { //Removed
            count = 0;
            flagAlarmSet = false;
            CancelAlarm(context);
            Log.d("Alarm cancelled", "Alarm");
            //} //Removed

            //start AsyncTask even if flag was not set, you could have internet the first time in
            try {
                Log.d("Executing TheTask()", "OK");
                new TheTask().execute("http://somedomain.tld/index.php?userId=12345678");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TheTask Execution Error", "FAIL");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (networkInfo == null) {
            if (!flagAlarmSet){
                Log.d("Internet is NOT connected.", "Schedule Retry");
                flagAlarmSet = true;
                SetAlarm(context);
                Log.d("Alarm Set", "Alarm");
            }
            else{
                count++;
                if (count >= 5){
                    Log.d("Internet is NOT connected.", "Max Tries Reached, Cancel Alarm");
                    count = 0;
                    flagAlarmSet = false;
                    CancelAlarm(context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String text = null;
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(arg0[0]);
            HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
            text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d("Test onPreExecute.", "OK");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.d("Result from server", result);

    }
}


public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, SmsReceiver.class);
    i.setAction("ActionRetry");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 4, 1000 * 60 * 4, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
}


public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SmsReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("ActionRetry");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

}

**EDIT: 1**

Updated the code, but still if no internet connection is available, **SetAlarm** is not being triggered. I am coming from PHP background. In PHP it is easy to set repeating tasks using cron jobs. But it is the first time when I am writing Java codes. Till now the **AsyncTask** is working perfectly, But I really don't have any idea where to increment **count** do all this stuff ?

**Edit: 2**

Updated Code.

**Edit: 3**

Updated code. Its working now.

Comment: You should use service or thread instead of AsyncTask

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but it is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Hence the comment. @Aman

Comment: Just create a `BroadcastReceiver` which triggered when there's no internet connection. It's a pretty way without check the connection every 4 minutes.

Comment: Hi @AnggrayudiH, I did not get what you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to solve this would be to use a PendingIntent and AlarmManager to re-schedule if no internet is available.

Something like this (you will need to update your flagAlarmSet and count where appropriate):

```
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    Log.d("Network is connected. Executing TheTask()", "OK");

    if (flagAlarmSet == true){
       flagAlarmSet = false;
       CancelAlarm(context);
    }

    new TheTask().execute("http://somedomain.tld/index.php?userId=12345678");

}

if (networkInfo == null) {
   Log.d("Network is NOT connected.", "FAIL");
   if (flagAlarmSet == false){
       Log.d("Network is NOT connected.", "Schedule Retry");
       flagAlarmSet = true;
       SetAlarm(context);
   }
   else{
      if (count > 5){
          Log.d("Network is NOT connected.", "Max Tries Reached, Cancel Alarm");
          flagAlarmSet = false;
          CancelAlarm(context);
      }

   }
}
```

And something like this for scheduling/canceling alarm:

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(context, SmsReceiver.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 4, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
 }

 public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, SmsReceiver.class);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.cancel(sender);
 }
```

Reference: [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example/8801990#8801990)

One more thing to note, if you are planning on using the message received, you would need to cache the message somehow for use in the re-scheduled PendingIntent.

See `getMessagesFromIntent()` documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#getMessagesFromIntent(android.content.Intent)

Example:
[Sending and Receiving SMS and MMS in Android (pre Kit Kat Android 4.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-and-mms-in-android-pre-kit-kat-android-4-4)

Edit:  re-set your count here:

```
         else{
            if (count >= 5){
                Log.d("Network is NOT connected.", "Max Tries Reached, Cancel Alarm");
                count = 0;
                flagAlarmSet = false;
                CancelAlarm(context);
            }
```

Edit 2: Ok, I think I see what the problem is.  You will need to add an action to the intent, and look for "ActionRetry" in `onReceive()`.

I just tested this and it works.

Take a look at the updated code below:

```
    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static boolean flagAlarmSet;
    static int count;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED) || action.equals("ActionRetry")) {

            Log.d("SmsReceiver Broadcast triggered", "OK");
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                Log.d("Network is connected. Executing TheTask()", "OK");
                Log.d("connected", "flagAlarmSet to: " + flagAlarmSet);

                //if (flagAlarmSet) { //Removed
                    count = 0;
                    flagAlarmSet = false;
                    CancelAlarm(context);
                    Log.d("Alarm cancelled", "Alarm");
                 //} //Removed

                 //start AsyncTask even if flag was not set, you could have internet the first time in  
                 try {
                        Log.d("SmsReceiver Broadcast triggered", "OK");
                        new TheTask().execute("http://somedomain.tld/index.php?userId=12345678");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("TheTask Execution Error", "FAIL");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }

            if (networkInfo == null) {

                Log.d("Network is NOT connected.", "FAIL");
                if (!flagAlarmSet){
                    Log.d("Network is NOT connected.", "Schedule Retry");
                    flagAlarmSet = true;
                    SetAlarm(context);
                    Log.d("Alarm Set", "Alarm");
                }
                else{
                    count++;
                    if (count >= 5){
                        Log.d("Network is NOT connected.", "Max Tries Reached, Cancel Alarm");
                        count = 0;
                        flagAlarmSet = false;
                        CancelAlarm(context);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String text = null;
            try {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(arg0[0]);
                HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
                text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return text;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("Test onPreExecute.", "OK");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.d("Result from server", result);

        }
    }


    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SmsReceiver.class);
        i.setAction("ActionRetry");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 4, 1000 * 60 * 4, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }


    public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SmsReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction("ActionRetry");
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @Daniel Nugent for your detailed answer and giving me the code. If I am not wrong I have to update flagAlarmSet in onPostExecute() if I get response from the server ?

Comment: No problem!  You can just update flagAlarmSet every time you set or cancel the alarm, I just updated the answer.  Also update the count every time `onReceive()` is called, and I would think re-set the count to zero in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Is it getting into the `SetAlarm()` function?   One more thing, it looks like you should just set the count back to zero (or one) when the max is reached.  As your code is now, you're creating a new count variable in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Sounds good!  Note that I didn't test the network code, just the SMS receive and subsequent re-scheduled broadcasts.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have tested your updated code on my phone. It's working perfectly when I get SMS when my phone IS NOT connected to Internet. Alarm is being sent & cancelled after max tries. But there are some issues when I switch on Wifi/Mobile Data after first Alarm being set. The code goes into infinite loop. Alarm is not being cancelled. Here is logcat which is perfec [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95549d8cc491cc6d90ff) Will paste another logcat after 30 minutes.

Comment: Now, I turned off Wifi on my phone & sent a test SMS. First AsyncTask failed because Internet was not connected. Then I turned ON wifi & the problem began. [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a70c5eea92f94d860704) is another logcat

Comment: Looking at the logs now.  Can you post your updated code to a gist as well?

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/427712253dbb833ba7d2) is complete code of **SmsReceiver.java**

Comment: It's hard to say why it's not getting into that case.  Try removing the `if (flagAlarmSet)`, take a look at the updated code in the answer.  For some reason it's not getting into that case.  Also log the value of `flagAlarmSet` when it gets into the internet connected case, just to get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot **Daniel**, You are genius. It works, I really appreciate your efforts. Once again thank you so much.